# FB Prophet Decompostion of Time Series

Tags: nlp, time-series, arima, facebook-prophet

Is there any way to decompose the time series into trend seasonality and its irregular components?
I want the output graph like this:
[image: Decomposed Time Series]

I would like the outputs for the trend, seasonality and irregular components to be visible separately varying over time.